# Codeforce problemset - Way too long words (RUNTIME_ERROR Exit code is 1)

Tags: java, runtime-error

I'am trying to solve CodeForce problem - Way Too Long Words. My code works fine in Eclipse but when I'm trying to submit it to CodeForce im getting RUNTIME_ERROR msg with 'Exit Code is 1' checker log. Could anyone please point me in right way to correct my mistake please. I tryied to change string but to be honest I have no idea how to solve this problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases=sc.nextInt();
        
        for (int i=0; i<(testCases+1); i++){
            String n=sc.nextLine();
            
            if (n.length() > 10) {
                char[] ch = n.toCharArray();
                
                System.out.println(ch[0] + String.valueOf(n.length()-2) + ch[n.length()-1]);


            }else{
                System.out.println(n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So if your input file has (on separate lines) `2` `globalization` `serialization` (or whatever, two too-long words) and you run it into your code it works?

Comment: hmm, no its only printed first word ```g11n```. Does that mean problem is in the way how I'm getting input?

Comment: (Actually it worked for me--I didn't think it would because the `for` loop condition seems wrong

Comment: I don't know if the problem requires you to do some error-handling, but you do get an exception if, when asked for the number of words, you enter a string that isn't a valid number, such as `abc`.

Comment: I solved the problem. My class file was included in package that I though was unimportant, but codeforce cant read file if its in package. Thank you all for your time.